# Program crashes when trying to print the name of an object

Tags: c++

As exercise I'm trying to implement the Hanoi tower through an Ordered Linked list.I've created the list,rods and disc class.Everything works fine,the Hanoi Tower too.
The problem arise when I want to print the rod name.I want to print something like:

```
Move Disc A to disc C
Move Disc A to disc B
```

Since I cannot print the object name directly,the Rod class constructor was built to give the object a name,but when I try to recall the getName method in Hanoi class,or to overload the operator<< in Rod class the program crashes.Here's my code,I've omitted the list,ad disk classes.

```
class Rod{
    private:
        OList<Disc> *r;
        char name;

        void _add(Disc x){
          r->insert(x);
        }

        void _print(){
        r->print();
        }

        void _rm(){
        r->rmDisc();
        }
    public:
        Rod(char name){
            r = new OList<Disc>();
            this->name = name;
        }

        Paletto *add(Disc x){
            _add(x);
            return this;
        }

        Disco *del(){
            _rm();
        }

        Paletto *moveTo(Rod *d){
            Disc *disc = del();
            d->add( *disc );
            return this;
        }


        void print(){
            _print();
        }

        char getName(){
            return name;
        }

        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,Rod &p){
            os<<p.getName();
            return os;
        }

};

class Hanoi{
    private:
        int n;
        Rod *A,*B,*C;
        void hanoiTower(int disc,Rod  *start,Rod *end,Rod *aux){
            if(disc == 1){
                cout<<"Move disc from "<<*start<<" to "<<*end<<endl;
                return;
            }
            else{
                hanoiTower(disc - 1,start,aux,end);
                cout<<"Move disc from "<<*start<<" to "<<*end<<endl;
                hanoiTower(disc - 1,aux,end,start);
            }
        }   
    public:
        Hanoi(int n){
            this->n = n;
            Rod *A = new Rod ('A');
            Rod *B = new Rod ('B');
            Rod *C = new Rod ('C');
        }

    void solve(){
        hanoiTower(n,A,B,C);
    }   
    int moves(){
        return pow(2,n)-1;
    }
};
```

The program performs the moves well until I trying to print the class given name,else crashes.Am I missing something here?I apologize in advance if my question seems too generic,or incomplete.

Comment: We're gonna need the error message that gets shown when it crashes as well.

Comment: You don't get a *single* compiler warning at the line `this->name = new name;` ?

Comment: Does the code sample, you have given us, even compile? `this->name = new name;` is invalid when `name` is defined as `char name;`, and `name` isn't even a type. And, how can it crash, if it can't be compiled?

Comment: @RustyX Warning? There are 2, separate, compilation _errors_ in that line alone.

Comment: I'm sorry that "new name " was a typo when I've posted the code.
Anyway ,I get a segmentation fault

Comment: BTW, you can eliminate the `this->` syntax by using different names for data members and method parameters.

Comment: What is an `OList`?  Why do you need a pointer to it (versus an instance)?

Comment: C++ is not Java; you don't need to allocate instances from dynamic memory to use them.  Get a better C++ reference or book.

Comment: The [`pow` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) returns floating point, not integer values.  Replace `pow(2,n)` with `1 << n`.

Comment: Where in the code do you print the rod name?  The `Rod::print` does not print the `name`.  Also, why do you need a public `print` that calls a private `print`?

Comment: The overloading of the operator << calls the method getName